# Link between left Poisson bracket, Hamiltonian vector field and the flow of the Hamiltonian vector field

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields, symplectic-geometry

I am going through *Variations on a Theme by Kepler*, Guillemin and Sternberg.

It is stated that a symplectic transformation on a manifold $\phi:X \rightarrow X$ induces a transformation on function.
$$f \rightsquigarrow f \circ \phi^{-1}
$$

They say: It turns out that every function $f$ on phase space generates a (local) one-parameter group, $\phi_t$, of symplectic transformations such that
$$\{f, g\} = \dfrac{d}{dt}g \circ \phi_{-t}\rvert_{t=0}
$$

My understanding is that they are referring to the flow of the Hamiltonian vector field $X^f = \{f, \cdot\}$
$$\phi_t = \exp(tX^f)
$$

I am however confused as to how everything fits together. We have for the flow $\rho$ of a complete vector field $X$ that:
$$\dfrac{d\rho_t(p)}{dt} = X(\rho_t(p))
$$

and so
$$X^f(g) = \{f, g\} = \dfrac{d}{dt}g \circ \phi_{-t}\rvert_{t=0}
$$

Intuitively, it seems to me that there is a minus sign error, indeed we are considering the change in $g$ as we travel against the flow, and I would expect this to be $-X^f(g)$

I am asking this because I am trying to understand the statement "left Poisson bracket by $f$ is the infinitesimal symmetry associated to $f$" and how the above statements fit together

---

EDIT:
According to Wikipedia, some authors define the Hamiltonian vector field with the opposite sign. My best answer is this must be the case here.
$$-\{f, \cdot\} = X^f
$$
Then indeed
$$X^f(g) = -\{f, g\} = -\dfrac{d}{dt}g \circ \phi_{-t}\rvert_{t=0}
$$
This can also be checked with the fact the Lie derivative for functions is $\mathcal{L}_X f = X(f)$ along with the general definition of the Lie derivative of a k-form:

$$\mathcal{L}_X \omega := \dfrac{d}{dt}(\exp(tX))^*\omega \Big \rvert_{t=0}
$$

giving
$$\mathcal{L}_X f = \dfrac{d}{dt}f \circ(\phi_t)) \Big \rvert_{t=0} = X(f)
$$

In this way, for a function $f$, $-\{f, \cdot\}$ = $X^f$ is the infinitesimal generator for the one-parameter family of symmetry transformations on the manifold
$$\phi_t:X\rightarrow X$$
$$\phi_t = \exp^{tX^f}$$

while $\phi^*_{-t}$ is the induced transformation on a function $g$

Is it thus correct to say the following ?
$$\dfrac{d}{dt}\exp(tX)\Big\rvert_{t=0}f = X(f) = \dfrac{d}{dt}f\circ\exp(-tX)\Big\rvert_{t=0}
$$

Comment: There are several different sign conventions regarding the definitions of Hamiltonian field and Poisson bracket. This is something terribly annoying, which you have to pay attention to every time you read a different text. Your comment about the authors referring to the Hamiltonian flow is indeed correct (at least mod 2).

Comment: Thank you ! I will have to be careful as I'm going through several different texts... Could you take a look at my final line, is it correct ?